# Direct payment with credit card paypal SDK in sandbox mode

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

I have integrated Paypal-SDK with my Android Application This is
   working fine when i am using PayPal, but when i am using direct
   payment with credit card it crass.... how can make direct payment
   using PayPal sdk.

Even the application i have created is showing like that.see the line features that are not - available for live transaction

[image: img]

Now more thing how can i get test credit card details including
    cvv so that i can request test transactions in sandbox mode.

Comment: If you suffered a crash, please add the relevant logs to your question.  Any credit card will be accepted on sandbox, as long as it follows the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

Comment: it showing on the app the features that are not enable for live transaction ..direct credit cards........

Comment: @akashyadav have you got how to test payment via credit card  in sandbox environment ??

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha nope...it seems not possible in india..but if directly contact to the bank they will give there api .after that this possible other wise paypal is only option

Comment: @akashyadav not possible n sand box as well as in live ???

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha no...:-(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Its giving this Disclaimer: 
"Unfortunately, due to recent product changes in the region, we are no longer able to allow Live DCC processing via RESTful APIs to Canada. We are continually looking for ways to expand our services, so please stay tuned. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause"

This mean that, paypal does not provide Live DCC processing to some areas in "Live api" (you can test it in test Api), you should check if it is the case with you. Either show your log cat.

While Using Test Api, two accounts are generated, one business account, another personal account. You can test it by transferring some amount (not actually transferred) by personal  account in your app and check it in your sandbox business account.
It may help you.